# Would the battery from a 13" MacBook Pro (2010) work in a 15" MacBook Pro 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

The battery of my MacBook Pro 15" (early 2011) died recently and I happen to have the battery from a 13" MacBook Pro (2010) handy.

Does anyone know of any reasons why this battery would not work?

I'm not concerned about battery life - I just want to be able to power the thing up.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. They're different sizes. Compare [iFixit's guide to replacing a 15" early 2011 battery](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Battery+Replacement/5889) to their [guide for a 2010 13"](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Battery+Replacement/4300):

15":

[image]

13":

[image]

Both batteries are roughly proportional to their cases, and the 15" has a substantially bigger case than the 13". Additionally, they're shaped differently - see the little notch in the top left of the 15" battery, which isn't there on the 13" battery. It physically won't fit.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware they were different sizes but thought I'd somehow be able to fit it in, but I tried and nope. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful that you mention the battery numbers that are printed upon them.

**I can confirm that the A1322 battery from a MacBook Pro 13'' loads correctly when attached to the MacBook Pro 15'' A1286 8,2 Early 2011.**

Both batteries operate at same voltage. The one from the 13'' has smaller capacity.

The connector of the A1322 batttery is at a different location than thus of A1321 / A1382 batteries, so that you cannot insert the battery into the MacBook 15'', at least without replacing the 2.5'' drive by a shorter SSD modul.

However, you can hold the battery with your hand. For me, this proved useful to check that a newer battery would fix a jerky mouse cursor issue.

Comment: Disclaimer: I assume that the battery load control is based on voltage, but I reject any responsability in case the battery would be overloaded or other issue.